# Angular unit test case for this.document.body.setAttribute()

Tags: angular, jasmine

`document.body.setAttribute('data', 'data1')` inside `ngOnInint()` in my component.

How can I write the unit test for this line?

Comment: what are you trying to assert with the test?  Are you trying to make sure that it gets called?  Are you trying to make sure that the data attribute exists on the element?  What is the value of this test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a unit test using Jasmine and TestBed in the following way:

```
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { YourComponent } from './your-component.component';

describe('YourComponent', () => {
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<YourComponent>;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [YourComponent],
    }).compileComponents();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(YourComponent);
  });

  it('should set data attribute on document body in ngOnInit', () => {
    const spy = spyOn(document.body, 'setAttribute');
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith('data', 'data1');
  });
});
```